Image became gray with Storypencil addon in Blender
Image became gray with Storypencil addon in Blender. is there a method to display in color ?



Probably best to ask the author that one. This is the manual section about it.

Outliner > Render,  select * Engine > Workbench*.
Lighting > Matcap > Set Attribute (means vtx color) or set to Random.
Then
Return back to VSE and choose Strip > Update Scene Frame Range
These steps fixes color problem of VSE
